# WordPress WPRocket: Lazy Load css background images

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I use WPRocket to optimize the performance of my wordpress website. 
WPRocket load images lazy, but not css background images. Do you have an hint for me how I can also lazy load background images?
I don´t want to install therefore a separate plugin.

Thanks for your hints.

Comment: It's not a separate plugin but may help as well: https://www.sitelint.com/blog/lazy-loading-css-background-images-for-better-website-loading-performance/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following, though I would check the compatibility for browsers you want to support:

```html
<img async="on" src="images/cat.png" />
```

Comment: OP wants to lazy load **background images**.

Answer (score 0):

you can follow the code:

```
<img src="example.jpg" loading="lazy" alt="..." />
<iframe src="example.html" loading="lazy"></iframe>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by explaining more about what the code does and how it helps the OP.